# Garage over basement is leaking

Tags: concrete, leaking

I live in Michigan and in the winter my garage floor is leaking (snow melt off the vehicles) into my basement. The floor has some minor cracks from settling (build in 1964). The garage floor has been patched and painted several times. I am looking for a long term solution to repair and seal the concrete floor to prevent leaking. The ceiling in the basement has flaking paint around the leaking area. What is the best approach to resolve?

Comment: Does your garage floor have a drain in it?  I've seen that in several cold-climate garages.

Comment: How are your garage and basement arranged? Are you sure that the water in your basement is coming from the garage floor?